# WIX error LGHT0284 - fully qualified name too long issue

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer issue. I had wix3.5 which has now been upgraded to wix3.8. I am using visual studio 2013. A TFS system is installed also, I have build servers etc.

When I run a build on visual studio on my wix project, it builds fine. However, when I run the build on the build server which is using wix 3.8 I get an error..
light.exe: Invalid file name specified on the command line:

```
obj\Release\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListen-us.txt
```

Error message:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

What is wierd is that, if on the build server, I uninstall wix3.8 and install wix3.5 I wont get this error! It builds fine. But with wix3.8 it fails. Whats even wierder is that I have another wix installer project with a longer name (by two characters) and that builds fine on the build server. Just this specific installer doesnt want to work. 
The full error is.

```
C:\B\522\GCF\Deploy.V1390.Connectors\Sources\V1390\CWW.ASG.GCF.Connectors\CWW.ASG.GCF.Connectors.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\B\522\GCF\Deploy.V1390.Connectors\Sources\V1390\CWW.ASG.GCF.Connectors\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj" (default target) (46) ->
(Link target) -> 
  light.exe : error LGHT0284: Invalid file name specified on the command line: 'obj\Release\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListen-us.txt'. Error message: 'The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.' [C:\B\522\GCF\Deploy.V1390.Connectors\Sources\V1390\CWW.ASG.GCF.Connectors\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj]

    534 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Here is the full command that is passed through once a run a build on visual studio 2013.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\Light.exe 
-out C:\B\522\GCF\Deploy.V1390.Connectors\Binaries\en-us\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.msi 
-pdbout C:\B\522\GCF\Deploy.V1390.Connectors\Binaries\en-us\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.wixpdb 
-v -cultures:en-us -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\\WixUtilExtension.dll" 
-ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\\WixNetFxExtension.dll" 
-ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\\WixIIsExtension.dll" 
-loc ..\..\InstallersCommon\English.wxl 
-sice:ICE80 -sice:ICE30 
–contentsfile obj\Release\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj.BindContentsFileListen-us.txt 
-outputsfile obj\Release\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj.BindOutputsFileListen-us.txt 
-builtoutputsfile obj\Release\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListen-us.txt 
-wixprojectfile C:\B\522\GCF\Deploy.V1390.Connectors\Sources\V1390\CWW.ASG.GCF.Connectors\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer\CWW.ASG.Connectors.AgentService.RemoteInstructionService.Installer.wixproj obj\Release\Product.wixobj obj\Release\ConfigUpdate.wixobj obj\Release\ProjectOutput.wixobj obj\Release\ServiceConfiguration.wixobj (TaskId:1781)
```

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the length of your .wixproj's name. The WiX MSBuild target uses the project name for intermediate files. That's what's causing the too-long path name.

Comment: Do you know why does it works with wix3.5? I dont understand this...has something changed in 3.8 to not allow this? I am using the exact same installer...same everything and it complains about character length. If i uninstall wix3.8 on my build server and install wix3.5 it will work fine agian.

Comment: WiX v3.6 added support for incremental builds, which required additional intermediate files to be written.

Comment: And Windows supports more than 260 characters, right?

Comment: @BobArnson Is it possible to turn off incremental builds?, i guess, since we run this on an buildserver, we don't need it that much, atleast since it's only giving us problems?